# Relative with repeated subject

Tags: translation, relative-clauses

Reading a basic text in my book, I found this short phrase with a relative clause:

> あの人達もバスに乗る人達ですか。

I would probably translate this sentence with:

> Even those people will get on the bus?

If my translation is correct, what's the difference between the sentence above and the following?

> あの人達もバスに乗りますか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A)  あの人達もバスに乗る人達ですか。
>
> B)  あの人達もバスに乗りますか。

You're absolutely correct. A and B mean the same thing, and B is more concise and to the point. A might sound redundant.

If a native Japanese kid write A, it may be proofread and corrected to B by their school teacher.

In other words, the sentence A is a typical-example-on-a-language-textbook sentence in order to teach you a relative clause. It may be unnatural in some of our actual daily life's settings, although it is grammatically correct and makes sense.